# Вывод объединенных ячеек excel в phpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel

Имеется таблица. В ней есть объединенные ячейки. Выводится массив, в котором значение указывается только в первой ячейке объединенных ячеек

```
       A      B      C      D

1      x      2      3      4

2             2      3      4

3             2      3      4

4      1      2      3      4
```

(A1:A3 - объединенные ячейки)
выведет массив, где A1 укажет значение "x", а A2 уже окажется пустым

Как вывести массив, где будет указано такое же значение **A1** в A2 и A3

Answer (score 0):

> *Как вывести массив, где будет указано такое же значение A1 в A2 и A3*

```
$rowArray = ['x', 'x', 'x'];
$columnArray = array_chunk($rowArray, 1);

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($columnArray, NULL, 'A1');

// Или без аргумента 'A1', т.к. по умолчанию эта координата уже задана
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($columnArray, NULL);
```

Ссылка на [документацию с примером](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/)

---

P.S.:

> Тестировать было не на чём, если пример не корректный, я его удалю.